# SiliCompressor library not working

Tags: android, video, compression

I using [SiliCompressor library](https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor) and i am getting mostly only 611 exact bytes in result and obviously compression is not working in any case. Is something wrong with my code?

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Uri>() {

        @Override
        protected Uri doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Uri newFileUri = null;
            try {
                File f = getDir("Videos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
                if (f.mkdirs() || f.isDirectory()) {
                    //compress and output new video specs
                    String filePath = SiliCompressor.with(UploadPostActivity.this).compressVideo(mVideoUri, f.getPath());
                    newFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return newFileUri;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Uri videoUri) {
            super.onPostExecute(videoUri);
            mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: Is your destination a file or a directory? What does the API support?

Comment: that's the problem, they didn't really tell that in the link, they just say "destinationAddress"